# Not able to connect to itunes connect for inapp purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4, in-app-purchase

In App Purchase was working fine with my App till yesterday in SandBox environment. but today whenever i try to buy the same InApp Purchase items, i'm unable to buy. i tried with deleting the App and reinstalling it. i have reset the settings of my device/devices also.i have tried with 3 different devices in which it was perfectly working till yesterday. Can anybody help me to find out the issue? Did any of you guys have faced the same thing or similar issues till the date?

Comment: and for some others too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026630/in-app-purchase-does-not-change-its-state-to-skpaymenttransactionstatepurchased

Answer (score 1):

Apple's sandbox servers are down today. It should work tomorrow.

Comment: Yes you are right Mr. Kumar, My In App purchase is working fine today. Thank you for your reply.